# Why is my torchserve docker image not working on google cloud run?

Tags: docker, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, google-cloud-run, torchserve

I have this docker image:

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.2

FROM continuumio/miniconda3

# install os dependencies
RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/man/man1
RUN apt-get update && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    python3-pip \
    vim \
    sudo \
    default-jre \
    git \
    gcc \
    build-essential \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# install python dependencies
RUN pip install openmim
RUN pip install torch
RUN mim install mmcv-full==1.7.0
RUN pip install mmpose==0.29.0
RUN pip install mmdet==2.27.0
RUN pip install torchserve

# prep torchserve
RUN mkdir -p /home/torchserve/model-store
RUN wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/AnimatedDrawings/releases/download/v0.0.1/drawn_humanoid_detector.mar -P /home/torchserve/model-store/
RUN wget https://github.com/facebookresearch/AnimatedDrawings/releases/download/v0.0.1/drawn_humanoid_pose_estimator.mar -P /home/torchserve/model-store/
COPY config.properties /home/torchserve/config.properties

# print the contents of /model-store
RUN ls /home/torchserve/model-store

# starting command
CMD /opt/conda/bin/torchserve --start --ts-config /home/torchserve/config.properties && sleep infinity
```

and in the same folder I have the following config.properties:

```
# Copyright (c) Meta Platforms, Inc. and affiliates.
# This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
# LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.

inference_address=http://0.0.0.0:8080
management_address=http://0.0.0.0:8081
metrics_address=http://0.0.0.0:8082
model_store=/home/torchserve/model-store
load_models=all
default_response_timeout=5000
```

it works perfectly fine locally but when I push it to gcloud run the following error occurs and the models do not run properly also /ping is returning healthy
here is the error:

```
org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerInitializationException: Backend worker startup time out.

at org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerLifeCycle.startWorker ( org/pytorch.serve.wlm/WorkerLifeCycle.java:177 )
at org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread.connect ( org/pytorch.serve.wlm/WorkerThread.java:339 )
at org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread.run ( org/pytorch.serve.wlm/WorkerThread.java:183 )
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker ( java/util.concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128 )
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run ( java/util.concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628 )
at java.lang.Thread.run ( java/lang/Thread.java:829 )
```

what is the issue?

Here are the starter logs: Not sure what to look for and hope this isn't too small to look through

Comment: 1) The CLI `ping` does not test your app. It pings the Google Front End (GFE) only. The GFE will always respond. 2) Cloud Run only supports one HTTP listening port (default is 8080). 3) Unless you adjust CPU settings, Cloud Run does not provide CPU time to background threads. More [details](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/container-contract). 4) Add the Cloud Run container startup logs to your post.

Comment: Please read this [guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). For Google Cloud logs, export the logs as text and then post the text in your question. Also, it is up to you to review the logs and only post the parts that are relevant to your problem. Posting everything usually means few will take the time to look at them.

Comment: 8080 is correct since that is the inference endpoint, the rest of the endpoint I am not interested in. the ping was to the docker containter, it returned the following json(jit returned healthy on my local machine) : {
  "status": "Unhealthy"
}

Comment: ok I will post the correct logs, I did not know how to export it as text. Thanks. How do you export the logs as text?

Comment: Ping does not return JSON. Please be specific in how you are testing. Status unhealthy often means that your Cloud Run container does not have a process responding to HTTP requests on the configured TCP PORT.

Comment: This docker image is supplied by an open source repo, the ping endpoint is one they recommend to request to check if the docker container is up and running. here is where I pulled the docker container from: https://github.com/facebookresearch/AnimatedDrawings. I am not changing anything from their configuration